# Multi-Process Shell in C, using Pipes [Linux]

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe, fork

I'm trying to code a shell in C that supports multi-pipe process handling, depending on the amount of separate processes given by the user, and each separated by a "|" symbol. The shell forks the amount of processes into a child for each process.

Here's an example:

```
texto1.txt = "Isto é o Texto 1"

$ cat texto1.txt | grep -c Isto
```

result: 1

But I'm having trouble with communicating between children and finally to the parent process.

Here's my current code for the `execpipe` function, which executes the pipe process, being `argv1` and `argv2` the 2 separate processes given by user input: (Example: `ls -l | wc -l`)

```c
int execpipe(char ** argv1, char  ** argv2)
{
    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);
    int i;
    pid_t p1, p2;
    p1 = fork();
    if (p1 == -1)
    { // error
        char * error = strerror(errno);
        printf("error fork!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (p1 == 0)
    { // child process

        close(fds[0]);
        dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[1]);
        if(execvp(argv1[0], argv1)<0){ // run command AFTER pipe character in userinput
            char * error = strerror(errno);
            printf("unknown command\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    { // parent process
        p2 = fork();

        if(p2==0){
            close(fds[1]);
            dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fds[0]);
            if(execvp(argv2[0], argv2)<0){ // run command AFTER pipe character in userinput
                char * error = strerror(errno);
                printf("unknown command\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }else{ //Parent waits for both of it's children
            wait(NULL);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent *must* close the pipe's write end to indicate the second process that no more data will come:

```c
            }
        }else{ //Parent waits for both of it's children
            close(fds[1]); // ++ add this line
            wait(NULL);
            wait(NULL);
        }
```

---

Little note: instead of

```
        char * error = strerror(errno);
        printf("error fork!!\n");
```

why not

```
        perror("fork");
```

Comment: Thank you! It's now solved, and works correctly